# Equivalent of `jax.lax.cond` for multiple boolean conditions

Tags: python, conditional-statements, jit, jax

Currently `jax.lax.cond` works for one boolean condition. Is there a way to extend it to multiple boolean conditions?

As an example, below is an untraceable function:

```
def func(x):
    if x < 0: return x
    elif (x >= 0) & (x < 1): return 2*x
    else: return 3*x
```

How to write this function in JAX in a traceable way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One compact way to write something like this is using [`jnp.select`](https://jax.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_autosummary/jax.numpy.select.html):

```py
import jax
import jax.numpy as jnp

@jax.jit
def func(x):
  return jnp.select([x < 0, x < 1], [x, 2 * x], default=3 * x)

x = jnp.array([-0.5, 0.5, 1.5])
print(func(x))
# [-0.5  1.   4.5]
```